# PHP Apache - PHP Gives internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Basically, even if I just use:

```
<?php
```

It gives me a 500 internal server error? Although, on command line, I can run `php index.php` and it runs fine?

I am using CENTOS and I have checked the logs, and got this:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

But I don't know if this relates or not? Any ideas to why it is just giving me an internal server error, even when just opening the tags?

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
~
```

EDIT:

Here is the config file:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerName mysite
    ServerAlias wmysite
    DocumentRoot /home/path/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ErrorLog  /usr/local/apache/error_log
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.co.uk combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.co.uk-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    UserDir enabled mywebsite
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup mywebsite mywebsite
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup mywebsite mywebsite
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid mywebsite mywebsite
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID mywebsite mywebsite
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mywebsite/public_html/cgi-bin/




    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/mywebsite/mywebsite.co.uk/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have replaced the site with `mywebsite`

EDIT 2:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Other .htaccess file

Comment: You have a recursive redirect internally. Check your rewrite rules.

Comment: Start by commenting out everything in your .htaccess file. Then add back in line by line as you test to identify which directive is causing the issue.

Comment: You must have another .htaccess file somewhere else, because there is no RewriteRule in the one you show, and it seems to be the problem. Or it is directly in your apache conf file.

Comment: @scandel I have commented out each line in both .htaccess files and still get's the same. I have the files in public_html but I don't know if this could be the problem or not..?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - Commented out all of the .htaccess file line by line still got the error

Comment: There must be something in your Apache config files then.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Apologies, I am running CentOS where will the apache config be?

Comment: Typically `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Also, what am I looking for in the apache config that could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the vhost configuration? It might be under `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: There may be a redirect there causing the errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  - I have updated my psot

Comment: I do not see a rewrite there either. Do you have any other config or htaccess files?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please see my EDIT 2: there is the rewrite

Comment: Comment all of that out, then test,

Comment: I think this is because of the `DocumentRoot /home/path/public_html` ; versions of Apache >= 2.2 don't allow DocumentRoot outside of /var/www/, unless you change your global Apache configuration. Try this : in /var/www, add a symbolic link to /home/path/public_html (say website) ; in the config file, replace the previous line by `DocumentRoot /var/www/website`.

Comment: @scandel No - This did not work